# Simple maths and display results? new to java

Tags: java

just making sure my maths is right.

Any hours over 40 are paid at one and one half the usual rate. It seems my overPay doesnt like to work? It seems when that the overtime method doesnt persist so it wont print out properly later?  any suggestions?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

     public class SalaryPay {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //declaration of fields
        double Level = 0;
        int SkillLevel;
        char Medical = 0;
        char Dental = 0;
        char Disability = 0;
        int hoursworked;
        double TotalPay = 0;
        double overPay = 0;
        double regPay = 0;
        char retirementplan = 0;
        double retire = (TotalPay*100) / 3;

        //enter Skill level
        System.out.println("Please press either 1 , 2, 3 according to your level");
        SkillLevel = sc.nextInt();

        switch(SkillLevel) { 
        case 1:
            Level = 19.00;
            break;
        case 2:
            Level = 23.00;
            break;
        case 3:
            Level = 27.00;
            break;
        }
        //Enter Hours worked
        System.out.println("Enter hours worked");
        hoursworked = sc.nextInt();
        regPay = hoursworked * Level;
        if (hoursworked <= 40) {
            overPay = hoursworked  * (Level * 1.5);
        } 

        //condition for Overtime
        /*if (hoursworked <= 40) {
            regPay = hoursworked * Level;
            overPay = 0;
        }
        else {
            regPay = hoursworked * Level;
            overPay = (hoursworked - 40) * Level * 1.5;  
            }*/


        //Insurance condition for skill 
        if(SkillLevel > 1) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to sign up for medical Insurance? (y/n)");
            Medical = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (Medical == 'y') {
                TotalPay = TotalPay -  23.50; 
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to sign up for Dental Insurance? (y/n)");
            Dental = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (Dental == 'y') {
                TotalPay = TotalPay -  21.00; 
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to sign up for Long-term Disability Insurance? (y/n)");
            Disability = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (Disability == 'y') {
                TotalPay = TotalPay -  17.00; 
            }

        //Retirement plan condition
        if(SkillLevel == 3) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to participate in the retirement plan? (y/n):");
            retirementplan = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (retirementplan == 'y') {
                TotalPay = TotalPay - retire;
            }


        //display results

            System.out.println("Hours worked this week : " + hoursworked
                            + "\nYour Hourly Pay Rate is : $" + Level
                            + "\nYour Payment is  : $" + regPay
                            + "\nYour Overtime Payment : $" + overPay);

                            if(Medical == 'y') {
                                System.out.println("Medical Insurance cost : -$23.50"); 
                            }
                            if(Dental == 'y') {
                                System.out.println("Dental Insurance cost : -$21.00");  
                            }
                            if(Disability == 'y') {
                                System.out.println("Long-term disability insurance cost : -$17.00");
                            }
                            if(retirementplan == 'y') {
                                System.out.println("Retirement Plan cost : -3%");
                            }
                            if(regPay < TotalPay) {
                                System.out.println("Error");
                            }
                            System.out.println("\nTotal earning after deduction : $" + TotalPay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your if-condition says "If the person worked less than or equal to 40 hours, set their overtime payment to that many hours times 150% of their regular rate." I doubt that's what you intend. More likely, you want to say "If hours were are greater than 40, then overtime hours = (Hours worked - 40), and overtime pay = overtime hours * (1.5 * regular pay)

Comment: Post in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: please clarify: regPay - should be total hours into rate.
and overPay should be the extra amount paid for extra hours i.e. the extra hours will be charged at a rate of one and half of the regular pay. eg: hours 45,so regPay = 45 * 27. and overPay = (45-40)*0.5 -- since the overpay is already charged in the regPay and only the difference(extra pay) is left.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more related to code review. So we can migrate it to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some errors in code.

Main Change:

regpay should be calculated for max 40 hours
overpay should be paid only for the extra hours.

```
/*modifed by raghu*/
if (hoursworked >= 40) {
    regPay = 40 * Level;
    overPay = (hoursworked -40)  * (Level * 1.5);
} else {
     regPay = hoursworked * Level;
}
```

Minor issue1:

also added TotalPay as follows

```
 TotalPay = regPay + overPay;
```

Minor issue2: seems when that the overtime method doesnt persist so it wont print out properly later
This is because the below loop was closed at the wrong place.
 if(SkillLevel == 3) {
 } //the loop was not closed at the right place

Look out for "raghu" to find the modified code.

Entire code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

     public class SalaryPay {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //declaration of fields
        double Level = 0;
        int SkillLevel;
        char Medical = 0;
        char Dental = 0;
        char Disability = 0;
        int hoursworked;
        double TotalPay = 0;
        double overPay = 0;
        double regPay = 0;
        char retirementplan = 0;
        double retire = (TotalPay*100) / 3;

        //enter Skill level
        System.out.println("Please press either 1 , 2, 3 according to your level");
        SkillLevel = sc.nextInt();

        switch(SkillLevel) { 
        case 1:
            Level = 19.00;
            break;
        case 2:
            Level = 23.00;
            break;
        case 3:
            Level = 27.00;
            break;
        }
        //Enter Hours worked
        System.out.println("Enter hours worked");
        hoursworked = sc.nextInt();
        /*modifed by raghu*/
        if (hoursworked >= 40) {
            regPay = 40 * Level;
            overPay = (hoursworked -40)  * (Level * 1.5);
        } else {
             regPay = hoursworked * Level;
        }
        TotalPay = regPay + overPay;
        //condition for Overtime
        /*if (hoursworked <= 40) {
            regPay = hoursworked * Level;
            overPay = 0;
        }
        else {
            regPay = hoursworked * Level;
            overPay = (hoursworked - 40) * Level * 1.5;  
            }*/


        //Insurance condition for skill 
        if(SkillLevel > 1) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to sign up for medical Insurance? (y/n)");
            Medical = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (Medical == 'y') {
                TotalPay = TotalPay -  23.50; 
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to sign up for Dental Insurance? (y/n)");
            Dental = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (Dental == 'y') {
                TotalPay = TotalPay -  21.00; 
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to sign up for Long-term Disability Insurance? (y/n)");
            Disability = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (Disability == 'y') {
                TotalPay = TotalPay -  17.00; 
            }

        //Retirement plan condition
        if(SkillLevel == 3) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to participate in the retirement plan? (y/n):");
            retirementplan = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (retirementplan == 'y') {
                TotalPay = TotalPay - retire;
            }
        }  // added by raghu

        //display results

            System.out.println("Hours worked this week : " + hoursworked
                            + "\nYour Hourly Pay Rate is : $" + Level
                            + "\nYour Payment is  : $" + regPay
                            + "\nYour Overtime Payment : $" + overPay);

                            if(Medical == 'y') {
                                System.out.println("Medical Insurance cost : -$23.50"); 
                            }
                            if(Dental == 'y') {
                                System.out.println("Dental Insurance cost : -$21.00");  
                            }
                            if(Disability == 'y') {
                                System.out.println("Long-term disability insurance cost : -$17.00");
                            }
                            if(retirementplan == 'y') {
                                System.out.println("Retirement Plan cost : -3%");
                            }
                            if(regPay < TotalPay) {
                                System.out.println("Error");
                            }
                            System.out.println("\nTotal earning after deduction : $" + TotalPay);
            //} --commented by raghu
        }
    }
}
```